# Eliminar duplicados de un objeto JS

Tags: javascript

**Cuando imprimo mi variable `var` de la manera `console.log(typeof(var), var)` devuelve**

```
object [{"idServicio":"27"},{"idServicio":"28"},{"idServicio":"27"},{"idServicio":"28"},{"idServicio":"28"},{"idServicio":"27"}]
```

**Como podria hacer para filtrar los elementos duplicados de mi objeto `var` y que retorne lo siguiente?**

```
object [{"idServicio":"27"},{"idServicio":"28"}]
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Nos mostrarías por favor lo que llevas al momento?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Estoy agregando y quitando elementos en un array ->  LocalStorage["quitarElementos"]. Los elementos estan ubicados en una DataTable. El tema es que dataTables tiene ciertas particularidades y cuando estas en una página de la tabla y queres modificar elementos que estan en otra pagina de la Datatable tenes que tener ciertas cosas en cuenta. Esto me trae como problema, que se me generan duplicados en la variable mencionada. Quisiera eliminarlos sin usar substr, tal vez alguien conocia una funcion ya sea para strings (le haria JSON.stringify) o para JSON. Gracias

Comment: Es decir, con respecto a esto no llevo nada. Con respecto al codigo de lo que estoy haciendo, mucho no te interesaria saberlo, estoy haciendo mis primeras practicas en desarrollo. Se me ocurre probar usar substr con una condicion, tener en cuenta la ubicacion de la cadena por el tema de las comas, y asi eliminar el elemento. Pero queria ahorrarme escribir todo eso, si es que alguien conocia una forma rapida de hacerla. Pero bueno, veo que va a ser mejor que me ponga a hacerla a ver que sale y despues pregunto de nuevo...

Comment: Revisa y adapta alguna de las respuestas de aquí seguro te funciona alguna https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Muchas gracias, era exactamente lo que buscaba, el spread operator con Set! Muchas gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En un array que no implique objetos sería tan sencillo como utilizar un `Set`, tu sintaxis sería:

```js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4];
const myFilteredArr = [...new Set(myArr)];
```

Ahora bien, tienes que tener en cuenta que eso con objetos no puede ser así, ya que dos objetos, aunque tengan la misma estructura y contenido no son considerados iguales, tendrías que elegir una clave de ese objeto como `valor de control`, típicamente `id`, aunque en tu caso sería `idServicio`.

Se me ocurre que podrías utilizar el método `reduce` de `Array` y añadir sólo los valores no existentes al nuevo array, de esta forma:

```js
const myArr = [
  {"idServicio":"27"},
  {"idServicio":"28"},
  {"idServicio":"27"},
  {"idServicio":"28"},
  {"idServicio":"28"},
  {"idServicio":"27"},
  {"idServicio": "19"},
];

const myFilteredArr = myArr.reduce(
  (prev, curr) => prev.find(el => el.idServicio === curr.idServicio)
  ? prev
  : [...prev, curr]
, []);

console.log(myFilteredArr);
```

Comment: Sé que @Aprendiz te ha enlazado una publicación en StackOverflow global, esta aportación pretende ayudar a aquellos que no entienden el inglés.